# How to get object value from an array in the local storage and compare it with a new value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to save an object into an array in the local storage,

but firstly I want to check either the object is already exist or not by comparing the existing Title in local storage with the new object's title. But I dont know how to do it.

```
const RecipeList = ({recipe}) => {


    const setData = () => {

      const newTitle = recipe.label;

        const existedFavRecipe = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('FavRecipes') || []);       

        // I want to write code that compare existedFavRecipe.Title with newTitle
        // if the title already exist it will give message and if not it will add the object into the local storage

            const NewFavRecipe = {
                Title : recipe.label,
                Image : recipe.image,
                Url : recipe.url,
                CuisineType : recipe.cuisineType,
                mealType : recipe.mealType,
                IngredientList: recipe.ingredients,
                Status : JSON.stringify(click)
            }
        existedFavRecipe.push(NewFavRecipe);
        localStorage.setItem('FavRecipes',JSON.stringify(existedFavRecipe));
    }
}
```

and the setData() will be triggered with onClick

Comment: You can use online react snippets for such questions: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-violet-fvbov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:
`const exists = existedFavRecipe.some((recipe) => recipe['Title'] == newTitle)`

You will iterate over `existedFavRecipe` array to check if the value already exists

```
if(!exists) {
  const NewFavRecipe = {
                Title : recipe.label,
                Image : recipe.image,
                Url : recipe.url,
                CuisineType : recipe.cuisineType,
                mealType : recipe.mealType,
                IngredientList: recipe.ingredients,
                Status : JSON.stringify(click)
            }
        existedFavRecipe.push(NewFavRecipe);
        localStorage.setItem('FavRecipes',JSON.stringify(existedFavRecipe));
}
```

Comment: great ! ,i tried using some() function before but did not understand and could not get the correct answer. Thanks :) !!